# Отфильтровать подсказки Google Place Api Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Здравствуйте, хочу отфильтровать результаты подсказок для конкретной страны (Россия), но Googl Place API for Android  в class AutocompleteFilter только из полей константа, в которой можно отфильтровать только тип.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отфильтровать результаты подсказок по России и Адресу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У метода `Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions` кроме `AutocompleteFilter` есть ещё `LatLngBounds`, который позволяет фильтровать результаты по координатам.

Область получается как-то так:

```
LatLngBounds latLngBounds = LatLngBounds.builder()
    .include(new LatLng(60.137332, 29.9322964))
    .include(new LatLng(60.197112, 30.234420))
    .include(new LatLng(60.120908, 30.579664))
    .build();
```

Но "внутри" он из этого получит две точки для ограничения области - с минимальными координатами и максимальными.

Либо передать их сразу в конструктор:

```
LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(60.117332, 29.9322964), new LatLng(60.197112, 30.234420));
```

Что тоже самое.

Comment: Если ограничивать по координатам, то страна не прямоугольная же, нужная область либо будет больше, чем страна, либо какие-то участки не захватит

Comment: Да, но API ничего лучше не предлагает.
Как костыльный вариант - в строку адреса всегда в начале подставлять "Россия, "